# Want select "from" and "to" dates from "from" calender and "to" Calender at a time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want select "from" and "to" dates from "from" calender and "to" Calender at a time.

Explanation:
I will be having a button when I click on it should popup a container having 'from' and 'to' calenders visible at a time, from these I should be able to select 'from' and 'to' dates, and when I click 'OK' in the popup I should get the 'from' and 'to' dates.

I am doing all this in jquery.

For this do we have any plugins or Can we customize data picker component in jquery.

Comment: share what have you tried so far. better if you can share it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Actually I have tried with kendo date picker But It couldn't get exact solution.